# Triangle on my pictures

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have taken pictures on my iPhone 8 Plus but when I try to look at them on my MacBook running Sierra 10.12, they all have a triangle on them with an exclamation point.

I am not able to edit the photos. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi Flip, you've tagged this post with Lion... is that the version of macOS you're running on your MacBook?

Comment: I'm new to this. it was working fine until I accidentally hit the live button, I have turned off the live but the triangle still shows. the MacBook & iPhone are brand new. I thought lion was a person. Didn't realize it meant a version.

Comment: Can you check you version? This can be found under the Apple menu and About this Mac

Comment: it's macOS Sierra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m guessing your MacBook isn’t on High Sierra and you’re viewing the new photo formats.

Have you looked at the settings app, camera, formats and checked JPEG instead of high efficiency? If you want to maintain high efficiency formats, upgrading now or eventually would be the plan.

Comment: bmike.....Yes! That worked. Thank you!  Now how do I get it off the 50 pictures that have the triangle or am I out of luck?

Comment: @Flip - The high-efficiency format is compatible with High Sierra- you can update your mac (if you want) through the App Store.

Comment: @Jackson1442 - Thank you Jackson1442! We are updating it. Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @Flip If you're updating your Mac to High Sierra which supports HEIF, you can put the setting on your phone to high efficiency and earn the benefits of the new format.